# Remove empty values from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I researched a lot of questions and answers posted on stackoverflow about the subject but I still couldn't find a solution to the following problem.

I need to generate an array from the text provided by this link, minus some specific lines: https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf. This part I was able to do.

PHP Code:

```
$arr = file('https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf');
$arr = preg_replace('/^(?![a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}\s).*$/i', '', $arr);
$arr = preg_replace ('/#/i', '',$arr);
$arr = preg_replace('/\t+/', ' ', $arr);
$arr = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $arr);
$arr = preg_replace('/ /', '~', $arr, 2);

foreach ($arr as $field) 
{
    $macList[] = explode('~', $field);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($macList);
echo "</pre>";
```

The problem is that when I use `print_r`, the first 52 sub-arrays are empty, plus some dozens at the bottom. I can't figure out how to remove them.

Reduced `print_r` output, because the full output returns 25770 sub-arrays:

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[47] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[48] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[49] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[50] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[51] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

    )

[52] => Array
    (
        [0] => 00:00:00
        [1] => 00:00:00
        [2] => Officially Xerox, but 0:0:0:0:0:0 is more common

    )
)
```

**Question:** How do I remove these 52 (0 to 51) empty arrays? Nothing I tried worked.

Comment: loop through them and use unset() as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to remove the empty keys, instead dont add the empty arrays in the 1st place:
EDIT is seems the 'empty' arrays are not in fact empty, but instead contain a single element with a space character. To remove you can combine `empty` with `trim` , `array_map` and `array_filter`:

```
  foreach ($arr as $field)
  {
      $temp = explode('~', $field);
      if(!empty(array_filter(array_map('trim', $temp))))
      {
          $macList[] = $temp;
      }
  }

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($macList);
  echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, the result I got here, after applying your recommendation, indicates that the empty sub-arrays are still being displayed. Maybe I applied your code incorrectly? [http://hastebin.com/geyusosiyo](http://hastebin.com/geyusosiyo)

Comment: Thanks again. I am so sorry for taking your time. The following code, after your new recommendation, still returns those empty arrays: [http://hastebin.com/umijaqufel](http://hastebin.com/umijaqufel).

Comment: @thiago Ahhh, now i see. The arrays are not empty, they contain a single space character. See my latest revision for a (tested, working) solution

Comment: I knew it was something I did wrong. Thank you for your solution and for being so patient.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of using `array_filter()` and **assuming** it is always an empty single element array:

```
$new_array = array_filter($array, function($elements) {
    return !empty($elements[0]);
});
```

Comment: Mr. McCreary, I sincerely thank you for your answer. I followed your recommendation but, unfortunately, the empty arrays are still being displayed. Link to the code I used to test: [http://hastebin.com/tucipapaco](http://hastebin.com/tucipapaco). Maybe I'm implementing your recommendation incorrectly?